No rule to make target 'build/main.o', needed by 'build'. Stop
Trying to learn makefile. Correct me if I'm understanding it wrong.
CXX_SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/*.cc)
CXX_OBJECTS = $(patsubst $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.cc, $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o, $(CXX_SOURCES))

Here patsubst will find all patterns with $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.cc
replace them with $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o
and input is $(CXX_SOURCES)
BUT patsubst will only do the renaming. It will not actually compile .cc files into .o files.
So to do that we create a target
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o
Which is same as the replacement parameter in patsubst.
So when patsubst statement executes, it comes to this target and compiles the file.
I tried commenting out
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.cc
    $(CXX_COMPILER_CALL) -c $< -o $@

But then I get the error
mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target 'build/my_lib.o', needed by 'build'.  Stop.
Why is it not simply renaming the files?
DEBUG = 1
INCLUDE_DIR = include
SOURCE_DIR = src
BUILD_DIR = build

CXX_STANDARD = c++17
CXX_WARNINGS = -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = $(CXX_WARNINGS) -std=$(CXX_STANDARD)
CPPFLAGS = -I $(INCLUDE_DIR)
LDFLAGS =

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
CXXFLAGS += -g -O0
EXECUTABLE_NAME = mainDebug
else
CXXFLAGS += -O3
EXECUTABLE_NAME = mainRelease
endif

CXX_COMPILER_CALL = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)

CXX_SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/*.cc)
CXX_OBJECTS = $(patsubst $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.cc, $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o, $(CXX_SOURCES))

##############
## TARGETS  ##
##############
create:
    @mkdir -p build

build: $(CXX_OBJECTS)
    @echo $(CXX_OBJECTS) Hi
    $(CXX_COMPILER_CALL) $(CXX_OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)

execute:
    ./$(BUILD_DIR)/$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)

clean:
    rm -f $(BUILD_DIR)/*.o
    rm -f $(BUILD_DIR)/$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)

##############
## PATTERNS ##
##############
#$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.cc
#   $(CXX_COMPILER_CALL) -c $< -o $@


I don't understand your question at all.  What do you mean by "simply renaming the files"?  There is no rule in your makefile to "rename files".  You have asked make to build a target named build/my_lib.o, and you have not given make any rule to know how to build build/my_lib.o (because you commented out the rule that tells it how to do so), so make reports it doesn't have any rule to build that target.  I'm not sure what the confusion is...?

I thought patsubst can find patterns and replace them. How I understood it is that it can find all .cc files and rename them to .o files if there is no instruction on how to convert .cc to .o file

That's not what it does. It doesn't "rename" anything, it just creates a new variable whose contents have some strings replaced according to the pattern you provided.

@tripleee oh ok I got it thanks. 'build: $(CXX_OBJECTS)'  has a pre requisite of  a target named same as the object file. So CXX_OBJECTS becomes build/my_lib.o and it searches for a target with same name but doesn't find it. Hence the error.
patsubst is not renaming the files, it is just working on strings. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

You should check first what Minimal reproducible example, and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example and then post strictly necessary stuff in your Makefile.
Doing so it will become clearer and you will be able to resolve it. If not then, at least you'll encourage people to read your source. As it is now I assume that you don't want to solve your problem, you want someone to dig into this mess and do it for you. That's not how it works here.

@tansy Noted. Will follow the same in future.

Funny thing is - if you did, you would answer your question.
